# error: '__assert_fail' was not declared in this scope

Tags: libtorch

Here's the error:

```
D:\libtorch_win_shared_with_deps_debug_1.8.1_cu102\libtorch\include\c10\macros\Macros.h:300: error: '__assert_fail' was not declared in this scope
     __assert_fail(#cond, __FILE__, static_cast<unsigned int>(__LINE__),  \
     ^
```

Comment: `Please post your code. The community cannot identify your problem if you do not show some code.`